# JavaScript/HTML (Mobile): When a page is partially scrolled, I can't do anything until it's finished scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a web page which has a scroll area, and some buttons outside of the scroll area. In mobile browsers or emulated mobile mode in pc browsers, when the scroll area is auto-scrolling (after the finger swipe on the screen quickly then remove the finger from screen), I can't tap the buttons or to do anything until the scrolling is finished. I tried Chrome and Safari, they all have the same problem. Is there any way to fix this? I want to trigger the button when it's scrolling.

[image: the web page layout is similar to this]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Where is the Image?

Comment: which javascript lib u r using? cordova ? or any other ?

Comment: @anshuVersatile, I'm using vue.js

Comment: @anshuVersatile, but I don't think this is caused by any specified js lib, I am wondering if it is cause by the browser itself, since the scroll animation was created by the browser, could it possible that the browser catches the touch event when it's animating?